# Possible to vertically partition a table without actually splitting into two tables?

Tags: sql-server-2019

From what I'm reading it may be best for me to put a large text field in it's own table and reference it via foreign key. It seems like I vaguely remember there being a way to effectively achieve the same thing w/o actually having to create two tables though.

Obviously it would be nicer not to have to write extra joins, but I also realize it's not a big deal to create a view. Still, if there's a way to achieve this through configuration that seems like it would be preferable.

What are my options?

Comment: As far as I am aware, 'vertical partitioning' is just splitting the actual tables and using foreign keys like you mentioned.

Comment: Without knowing what you have read, what problem are you trying to solve? With a MAX datatype (e.g. `varchar(MAX)`), SQL Server will internally store large values in separate pages so you don't incur overhead retrieving data unless the large value is included in queries.

Comment: @DanGuzman Good point, though I also had in mind many values that could be small enough to be included in the page but still large enough to slow down performance even when the column isn't included in a query. However, I've basically come to the conclusion that what I thought existed doesn't... and even if it did it wouldn't necessarily solve anything in a more efficient way (hence why such a feature probably doesn't exist). If someone else wants to explain this better than I can in an answer I will mark it... otherwise I will soon self answer to explain my findings in more detail.

Comment: It would make sense to move large varchar columns that you need to query infrequently to their own table purely so that more rows for the data you need to query frequently can fit on a data page thus improving memory efficiency and reducing IO; this is a design decision though, not a feature of sql server.

Comment: Exactly my conclusion.... that it all depends on whether you need to load the text every time or infrequently. And if both scenarios are common (and assuming disk space is not an issue) then I would suppose creating an index on everything but the text field would give the best of both worlds, right?

Comment: Or more realistically, various indexes as appropriate for different tasks, but generally speaking you get the point.